# Adding a scrollbar to QMessageBox

Tags: c++, qt4, qmessagebox

I am doing a project with Qt. After calling a QMessageBox, I have found that there are too many words to be printed and I want a scrollbar in the QMessageBox.

Is it possible to make a scrollbar to the text so that I will not very long QMessageBox.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You will have to implement your own message box with that behavior.

See: http://www.qtforum.org/article/18183/messagebox-with-qscrollbar.html?s=bdd81f89ba19b4b5a4120d2b5cf6d1cc02aa01f5#post109324

Comment: I have searched it and tried it. But when I included the files, many errors occurred. The output says there are declaration errors, which means it cannot completely replace the QMessageBox?